# Win2k3s - Low colours on Remote Dekstop

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

The problem I am experiencing is a slight variation on the common issue with colour-count on RD.  When connecting RD from a win7 machine to a win2k3s machine via the Administrator account I get a desktop which only shows 256 colours.  Interestingly if I connect to the same remote machine with a different account but otherwise identical connection settings, I get the full 16bit colour depth.

I have researched and understand the problem that by default RD gives 256 colours to a session that is using a high resolution.  To counter this I have added the 'AllowHigherColorDepth' registry value.  I have also ensured the 'Remote Desktop Connection/Display/Chose the colour depth for the remote session' entry is set to 'Highest Quality (32Bit)" on the win7 machine.  In tandem, on the remote win2k3s machine I have set the "Terminal Services Configuration/Connection/RDP-Tcp Properties/Client Settings/Limit Maximum Colour Depth" entry to "16bit".  None of this makes any difference.

I wondered if there are any other solutions you chaps could suggest?'

Comment: `I have researched and understand the problem that by default RD gives 256 colours to a session that is using a high resolution` - I've never heard of that nor can I replicate that. Where did you get that information? Can you post a link to your source?

Comment: Sure thing: [link]http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942610  Its mentioned in that post about how to fix it.  Unfortunately the fix does not work for me.

Comment: OK, why did you do everything you did instead of installing the hotfix to resolve this?

Comment: As I read it, all the hotfix does is apply the registry subkey and setting?  Maybe I got hold of the wrong end of the stick.  However the more I have delved into this the more I think it is a problem not directly linked to RD.  If I log in person at the machine, then go to the appearances/themes section of desktop properties it gives me the error "Visual styles could not be loaded".  However if I again log in under a different username the appearance page works perfectly...  'SFC /Scannow' did not help.  I think there must be some problem with the 'Administrator' user account.

Comment: No, the hotfix also replaces file Rdpwd.sys. So you should install the hotfix.

Comment: I thought that might do it then - but sadly not...  Given that the hotfix doesn't work and I'm having the desktop 'appearance' issues I am fairly certain the RD low colour thing is just a manifestation of the 'Visual style could be loaded because the file failed to load' issues.  Any ideas why this should only happen on one user account - 'Administrator' - but on no others?  To reiterate for clarity, if I do exactly the same thing - attempt to apply the 'Windows Classic' theme - on a second account I have no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just to wrap this one up.  The problem I described above seems most likely now to be an emerging symptom of underlying failure within the system hard drive.  At some point between installation and my noticing the issue there had been a great deal of uncorrectable surface damage done to the drive.  Strangely neither 'chkdisk' (without a surface test) nor 'sfc' seemed to detect this.  However Win2003 was reporting its inability to read various themes and display-related libraries because the files themselves were heavily corrupt.  I confirmed this with four complete scans using both the manufacturer's own low-level tools and the far superior **MHDD32**.  I highly recommend the latter to anyone attempting to investigate an intermittent file system problem or salvage data from such.

This was obviously not a solvable issue - especially as the drive itself was maddeningly only just beyond its year's warranty!  Nonetheless I thank anyone who took the time to look this question over.